# Simple C++ tag library for OGG needed

Tags: c++, ogg

I am looking for a C++ library that can tag ogg files **easily** meaning with a simple function like

```
write_ogg_tag("file.ogg", tag_data); // where tag_data contains artist, album ...
```

Is there a solution?

Also, do some of the solutions apply to MP3, FLAC, etc.? (ogg suffices, only asking because I'm curious)

Comment: Which libraries have you tried and found not easy enough?

Comment: Only libtheora and libogg by now. I found them way to complicated for my purposes... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything else is better or simpler than [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html). It applies to all popular formats. You can find details on the API [here](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/).

An alternative and much more involved way is using the base components like `libogg` and use the low-level format specific API, but that does not seem like what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, looks really easy, and it's already installed on my computer... Thanks a lot, exactly what I've been looking for!